# Fetch mysql row unless it's a duplicate, in which case ignore it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, fetch

I'm stuck on this.  What I'm trying to do is this.  A notification system.  When I comment on something, I need it to get all other users who previously commented and send them a notification as well as the owner of the item, that the post has new activity.

Here's the issue.  I'm populating a comment box underneath the post, and you write your comment, and hit enter, and it sends the post ID your commenting on, as well as your username and comment to a php script which calls a function to send a notification.

So, as hidden inputs, I'm pulling out from the database in the comment form, anyone who has previously commented on the post.  Here's the issue, let's say User A has commented 3 times, the database would have him as a commenter 3 times, so his name will be pulled into the comment form as three different inputs.  Here is some code for the mysql call that is pulling the previous commenters:

```
// Query the comments to see who has commented.
// Their username will be in the owner column.
// $postid is being pulled from the actual post id that you are commenting on.
// At this point the post content and previous comments are already
// processed, this is just processing the comment form.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid = '$postid'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="'.$row['owner'].'" />';    
}
```

If user A has commented 4 times, the comment form would look something like this, then:

```
<form id="comment-form-##">
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="usera" />
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="usera" />
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="usera" />
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="usera" />
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="userc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="userc" />

// And the id of the post you're commenting on
    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="24" />

// And then the actual input box for your comment:
    <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment" />
```

So how can I pull the users who have previously commented, and skip their multiple listings in the database.  Ideally, I'd like the comment form to look like this when complete:

```
<form id="comment-form-##">
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="usera" />
    <input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="userc" />

// And the id of the post you're commenting on
    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="24" />

// And then the actual input box for your comment:
    <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment" />
```

Hope there is a way to do this as this was my first inclination on how to notify previous commenters to the new activity.  Thanks for any and all help I can get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner
  FROM comments
  WHERE postid = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suggest, insert all owners into an array, then use array_unique on it so duplicates are removed, then run a foreach loop that would display the hidden form fields

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid = '$postid'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$owners = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) $owners[] = $row['owner'];
$owners = array_unique($owners);
foreach($owners as $owner) echo '<input type="hidden" name="commented[]" value="'.$owner.'" />';
```

Also, let me mention that I think this is not the best way to do what you want. These hidden form fields could be tampered with easily and you would be sending notifications to the wrong people.

Since you send the post_id as a hidden form field to a page that notifies people, I suggest you modify that page that so that it queries everyone who commented on that specific post_id except the one that is currently commenting and send them a notification instead of simply adding their ids in a hidden form field.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid = '$postid' GROUP BY owner
```

Comment: This would have worked as well as the one I marked as the answer.  The only reasons I marked that one was because I really only needed the 'owner' column, and I was going to work my way down the list of these responses until I found one that worked, so naturally I tried that first.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `owner` from comments where `postid` = '$postid'";

Then you'll get a list of the users who've commented without any duplicates.